# In Scikit, How Do You Fix Value Error When Predicting?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

**The following code gives me the following error:** *ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 3)) while a minimum of 1 is required.*

The error is produced in line where prediction is invoked. I am assuming there's something wrong about the shape of the dataframe, 'obs_to_pred.' I checked the shape, which is (1046, 3).

What do you recommend so I can fix this and run the prediction?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

from patsy import dmatrices
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import scipy.stats as stats
from sklearn import linear_model

# Import Titanic Data
train_loc = 'C:/Users/Young/Desktop/Kaggle/Titanic/train.csv'
test_loc = 'C:/Users/Young/Desktop/Kaggle/Titanic/test.csv'
train = pd.read_csv(train_loc)
test = pd.read_csv(test_loc)

# Predict Missing Age Values Based on Factors Pclass, SibSp, and Parch.
# In the function, combine train and test data.
def regressionPred (traindata,testdata):

    allobs = pd.concat([traindata, testdata])
    allobs = allobs[~allobs.Age.isnull()]
    y = allobs.Age

    y, X = dmatrices('y ~ Pclass + SibSp + Parch', data = allobs, return_type = 'dataframe')
    mod = sm.OLS(y,X)
    res = mod.fit()

    predictors = ['Pclass', 'SibSp', 'Parch']
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(allobs.ix[:,predictors], y)

    obs_to_pred = allobs[allobs.Age.isnull()].ix[:,predictors]
    prediction = regr.predict( obs_to_pred ) # Error Produced in This Line ***

    return res.summary(), prediction

regressionPred(train,test)
```

In case you may want to look at the dataset, the link will take you there: [https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data](http://titanic%20datasets)

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
allobs = allobs[~allobs.Age.isnull()]
```

you define `allobs` as all the cases with no `NaN` in `Age` column.

Later, with:

```
obs_to_pred = allobs[allobs.Age.isnull()].ix[:,predictors]
```

you do not have any case to predict on as all `allobs.Age.isnull()` will be evaluated to False and you'll get an empty `obs_to_pred`. Thus your error:

> array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 3)) while a minimum of 1 is required.

Check the logic what you want with your predictions.